# Disabling pointer events only on a child element through CSS only

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a userscript for a page, so I don't have control over the original HTML. Also, because of the way the page loads and the script works, for various reasons I can *only* use CSS modifications here, and the modifications can only be on page-level CSS (not per-element style attributes).

So, the issue is, there is a large `a` element that has a hierarchy of `div`s in it. I would like to disable pointer events *only* on one of the child `div`s, while leaving everything functioning as normal everywhere else on the `a`. For example:

```js
const disableBottomPointerEventsStyle =
  '.bottom { pointer-events: none; cursor: default; }';

$('#test').click(function () {
    $('<style/>')
        .attr('type', 'text/css')
        .text(disableBottomPointerEventsStyle)
        .appendTo(document.head);
    $(this).toggle();
});
```

```css
.link { display: flex; width: 10ex; height: 20ex; margin-bottom: 1ex; }
.wrapper { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
.top { border: 1px solid red; }
.bottom { border: 1px solid blue; }
div { flex-grow: 1; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- example of page structure: -->

<a class="link" href="about:blank">
   <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="top"></div>
       <div class="bottom"></div>
   </div>
</a>

<!-- ========================== -->

<button id="test">Test</button>
```

In that example there is an `a` with some `div`s in it, and the goal is to disable pointer events only on the blue `div` on the bottom while leaving everything else as-is.

To use the example press the *Test* button; this will insert a style rule in the document. My current best attempt is the value of `disableBottomPointerEventsStyle`:

```
.bottom { pointer-events: none; cursor: default; }
```

This has no effect.

So my question is, is it possible to do this *only* by modifying a page-wide CSS rule and, if so, how?

Note that this is fundamentally a CSS question, the JavaScript is pretty much incidental here.

Comment: `const disableBottomPointerEventsStyle =
  '.link { pointer-events: none; cursor: default; } .top {pointer-events: auto; cursor:pointer;}';`
I know this doesn't exactly meet your usecase, but this was the only way I could get this done. By selectively enabling pointer-events. And `pointer-events` work in the same way as visibility does

Comment: If you look at the stylesheet of the page you're working on, you'll notice that the user-agent automatically adds styles to the `a` element. The UA automatically adds `cursor: pointer;` and the default value of `pointer-events` is `auto`. To achieve what you're looking for, you first have to "undo" the UA styles first i.e set `a.link { cursor: none; pointer-events: none}`. Then for every direct descendant (except the one you want) add `cursor: pointer; pointer-events: auto;`. I'm aware this is not exactly what you're looking for, but this seems to be the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret is to disable natural `a` behaviour, and enable it in the `child`.
I used hardcode `a.link` - to minimise a risk of side effects.
Supported https://caniuse.com/?search=pointer-events - should be good.

```css
.link { display: flex; width: 10ex; height: 20ex; margin-bottom: 1ex; }
.wrapper { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
.top { border: 1px solid red; }
.bottom { border: 1px solid blue; }
div { flex-grow: 1; } 

a.link{ pointer-events: none}
div.top{ pointer-events: auto}
```

```html
<a class="link" href="about:blank">
   <div class="wrapper">
       <div class="top"></div>
       <div class="bottom"></div>
   </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Awesome; I didn't know that disabling `a` but enabling a child would still trigger the link. Thanks. Something like `.link { pointer-events: none; cursor: default; } .wrapper div:not(.bottom) { pointer-events: auto; cursor: pointer; }` also works in my case and lets me stay unaware of any other divs that may be in the wrapper besides the one I care about.